# WCF client unable to reflect type or serialize interface

Tags: wcf, soap, svcutil.exe

We are writing a .NET 6 client for a SOAP web service that appears to be implemented with MS: .svc or .asmx. Adding the service reference successfully creates the proxy class. Invoking it returns the following.

Exception
{"There was an error reflecting 'SubmitReportMessage'."}

InnerException
"Cannot serialize interface ServiceReference1.EmissionTest."

I've tried dotnet-svcutil, VS2022 to both the online service and the downloaded .wsdl and/or .xsd.

The WSDL returned from https://the-service/EmissionTest?singleWsdl node
   `<xs:sequence> <xs:any processContents="lax"/> </xs:sequence>`
I tried replacing it from a more detailed .xsd but got the same results.

Question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496740/cannot-serialize-interface" suggested implemented the class. I've never needed to do this with other SOAP services and expected adding the ServiceReference would handle this.

Question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002886/can-i-use-an-interface-as-a-type-in-my-wcf-client-code" suggested creating a base class common to both service and client, but the service is from a third party.

Any help would be appreciated.